# Animate UILabel to offscreen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to animate UILabel `name` from it's position to offscreen (left side), but my animation animates the label from offscreen (left) to it's position, which is set in storyboards. How can I get the animation that I want?

My code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        CGFloat newCenterX = self.name.center.x + self.view.bounds.size.width;
        self.name.center = CGPointMake(newCenterX, self.name.center.y);
        self.name.alpha = 1;
    }];
```

Comment: Where is this being called?

Comment: In `slideToLeftWithGestureRecognizer` method

Comment: It appears to me that this code animates the label off to the right.

Comment: I have an array of strings and every slide gesture changes UILabel text to the another string from array. When I have only 1 string in array, animation works how it's supposed to work, but when I have > 1 string, animation is reverse

Answer (score 0):

Here the below code means if your label present in the middle of Viewcontroller which animate to the left of the screen which position is zero, please check it out,

```
CGRect actual_frame_from_storyboard = self.name.frame;
    actual_frame_from_storyboard.origin.x = 0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^
    {
        self.name.center = actual_frame_from_storyboard;
    }];
```